# How can I draw myname (or any string) on the wall paper of mobile in J2ME?

Tags: java-me

How can I draw myname (or any string) on the wall paper of mobile through a J2ME program?

Comment: This is impossible with J2ME.

Answer (score 0):

If use Canvas or CustomItem it is possible.Inside the paint method we should insert a command "g.drawString()". here g is an object of Graphics class.The syntax of drawString() is 
public void drawString(String text, int x, int y, int anchor)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do something similar for Sony Ericsson devices using a standby MIDlet and assigning it as wallpaper on the device.
Take a look at this document from SE.

[How to create a standby MIDlet / Java wallpaper in Java ME](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/community/docs/DOC-1705)